# Why should vlucas/phpdotenv not be used on production environments?

Tags: drupal-8

I am using Drupal 8 and I can see that there is already the vlucas/phpdotenv library in the vendor folder in my project.

So I thought about using it and hence was going through the Github page of the library:[doetnv library](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)

The following is a part of the documentation:-

> phpdotenv is made for development environments, and generally should not be used in production. In production, the actual environment variables should be set so that there is no overhead of loading the .env file on each request. This can be achieved via an automated deployment process with tools like Vagrant, chef, or Puppet, or can be set manually with cloud hosts like Pagodabox and Heroku.

My questions are:

1. If it can be used in dev environment, what is the problem with using it in production environment?
2. How can the automated deployment tools mentioned be used to load the environment variables?

Comment: "...so that there is no overhead of loading the .env file on each request..." - from my understanding, you just need to cache all `.env ` variables for production. So your app doesn't have to load .env file on each request. Have a look [Laravel's approach](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration#configuration-caching) on using .env, maybe it will help you understand better.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand better.
But I have one question then after reading about Laravel's approach.
What if there is only 1 config file in my project like the .env file? Then if I run the command for Laravel, it will again create a new file with the same data. In that case, will usage of this library cause any problem?

Comment: Each time you run `php artisan config:cache` command, it will regenerate the cached config file. In other words, yes, Laravel will need to parse .env file again but only for that one time.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But what I was saying is that if I only have 1 config file then running the command will again generate 1 config file only. So in such a case, using the library is not a problem I guess.

Answer (score 1):

> If it can be used in dev environment, what is the problem with using it in production environment?

If you have seen the usage of dotenv package, it is shown in its document that on each request the load function will be executed, which will reduce the request execution and can lower down the page performance.
https://packagist.org/packages/vlucas/phpdotenv

> How can the automated deployment tools mentioned be used to load the environment variables?

This the part of the configuration automation tools like Ansible, salt-stack, puppet. These tools are used to configure the nodes in the pool, you can add a configuration task to create the environment variables inside it. So you need to first learn these tools and create the tasks for provision environment variables.

Comment: Just to give some context - I tested it on E5-2620 v3 2.4 GHz / SSD / PHP 7.4 opcache / FPM / 1000 requests. With ~10 variables in a single .env we're looking at 1.0-1.5 ms per request, with 40-ish variables ~3ms per request. One needs to decide if it's a lot or not.